# Javascript: input type="email" element value is not updating using .value attribute

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, input

This seems like a weird problem. I am working on a extension which supports multiple browsers. In the process, when the user lands on a login page, my plugin checks for the username and password input fields and fills them up with some text values. I have a website which has `input[type="email]` and `input[type="password"]` input elements for username and password respectively.

My plugin is able to identify and select the input elements using selectors but when the input element value is updated using `element.value = "<email>"`, I can see the updated value on the UI but the "value" attribute of the `<input>` on HTML is not updated.

After some rigorous trails, I found out I need to trigger input event to update the value attribute of the `<input>` element which is working on chrome, Firefox, safari and edge but not on IE. For all the browsers I am able to see the "value" attribute is updated as soon as the input event is triggered for the element but not for IE. What might the reason? IE version is 11.0.9600.

```js
function updateInput(element, value){
 element.value = value;
  //you can see the element outer HTML is not updating
  window.alert(
  "element.value: " + element.value +" \n element:" + element.outerHTML);
}

updateInput(document.querySelector('input[type="email"]'), "e@e.com");
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="auth0-lock-input-block auth0-lock-input-email">
    <div class="auth0-lock-input-wrap auth0-lock-input-wrap-with-icon">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="auth0-lock-input" placeholder="yours@example.com" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" value>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="auth0-lock-input-block auth0-lock-input-show-password">
      <div class="auth0-lock-input-block auth0-lock-input-password">
        <div class="auth0-lock-input-wrap auth0-lock-input-wrap-with-icon">
          <input type="password" name="password" class="auth0-lock-input" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" value placeholder="your password">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you interested in the value attribute or the value property? They're not the same thing. The attribute is used for the default value of the property, but changing one doesn't change the other.

Comment: Oh, the main problem is the input fields are getting reset (to empty values) when focus or blur events triggered on them. The values are only being reset when they are added by JavaScript code. If they are added by manual key press then the behavior is normal. So I am searching for ways to overcome the input fields reset.

Comment: Its working normally on chrome as it has the value attribute set by the code. On IE the value attribute is being set, so I thought that is where the issue might be. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: I tried IE11 in BrowserStack (I'm on a Mac, can't run IE locally). I don't see any problem with the email field in the snippet.

Comment: And Chrome shows `value=""` in the alert.

Comment: Maybe you have another IE plugin that's conflicting?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think something in `main-client.js` is doing this.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the `auth0-lock-input` class?

Comment: I tried to remove the class on the input element assigned the value through `element.value = "<value>"` on console but its still resetting the value on focus or blur.

Comment: There are many utility scripts being loaded on that page, and they're minified so it's hard to understand what they're doing. I suspect one of them is doing this.

Comment: Yes, @Barmar. Is there any way to override this behaviour and make it not to reset the input on blur/focus when value is through Javascript? I tried in many alternative ways, nothing seems to work.

Comment: You need to find the code that's doing it and change it so it doesn't do it.

Comment: This isn't being done by the browser itself. One of your scripts is trying to preserve the input value.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I ll try to find which part of code it is.